# subnormal operator

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I know that ‎$‎‎u\in B(H)$ ‎is a‎ ‎normal ‎operator if ‎‎$‎‎uu^*=u^*u$‎.

I ‎know ‎that ‎if ‎‎$‎u‎$‎‎ ‎is ‎subnormal ‎‎‎‎then ‎‎‎ ‎‎$‎‎uu^*‎\neq ‎u^*u$ ‎(like unilateral shift operator).

‎‎
My problem is:"If  ‎$‎‎u\in B(H)$ is subnormal then ‎$‎‎u^*u‎\geq uu^* ‎‎‎$‎"

Comment: Funny name for an operator xDDD

Comment: Yes, it is. Condition $u^*u\ge uu^*$ is called hyponormality. That is, every subnormal operator is hyponormal.

Comment: i want to show that two minimal normal extensions of $u$ is unitary equivalent.How?

Comment: Does $u$ admit minimal normal extension?

Comment: @alexv these are many questions. I think is better edit your original post including your questions

Comment: @alexv this is not true every normal operator is subnormal, in finite dimensional case we can prove that $T$ is subnormal operator iff $T$ is hyponormal iff $T$ is normal

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Condition $u^*u\ge uu^*$ is called hyponormality.

Proposition: Let $M$ a subspace of $H$ and $T\in B(H)$. If $M$ is $T$-invariant, then $(T|_M)^*=PT^*|_M$, where $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto $M$.

Now, if $S$ is subnormal in $H$, there is a superspace $K\ge H$ and a normal operator $N\in B(K)$ such that $N|_H=S$ and $H$ is $N$-invariant. Let $P$ the orthogonal projection of $K$ onto $H$. By the proposition,  S^*=PN^*|_H and $\|S^*x\|^2\le\|Nx\|^2$ for all $x\in H$. Thus $\langle S^*x,S^*x\rangle\le\langle Nx,Nx\rangle$ for all $x\in H$, and, since $N$ is an extension of $S$ in $H$, this is equivalent to $\langle SS^*x,x\rangle\le\langle Sx,Sx\rangle=\langle S^*Sx,x\rangle$ for all $x\in H$, which proves $SS^*\le S^*S$.

On the other hand, no. Normal extensions aren't unitary equivalent, but minimal normal extension always exists, and any to minimal normal extensions are unitary equivalent.